# How to connect ffi to node-webkit(nwjs)?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, ffi, nwjs, node-ffi

So, I try to use ffi in my node-webkit(nwjs) application, but my code doesn't work.
There is my index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <script>
    var ffi = require('ffi');
    var ref = require('ref');
    var int = ref.types.int;

    var platform = process.platform;
    var mathlibLoc = null;

    if (platform === 'win32') {
      mathlibLoc = './math.dll';
    } else if (platform === 'linux') {
      mathlibLoc = './math.so';
    } else if (platform === 'darwin') {
      mathlibLoc = './math.dylib'
    } else {
      throw new Error('unsupported plateform for mathlibLoc')
    }

    var math = ffi.Library(mathlibLoc, {
      "add": [int, [int, int]],
      "minus": [int, [int, int]],
      "multiply": [int, [int, int]]
    });
    
    var result = null;

    result = math.add(5, 2);
    console.log('5+2=' + result);

    result = math.minus(5, 2);
    console.log('5-2=' + result);

    result = math.multiply(5, 2);
    console.log('5*2=' + result);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And it is very interesting that my script doesnt work then I try to write this line

> var ffi = require('ffi');

And there is no matter what I try to run after this line, it doesnt work...

So, after I dug up all the Internet, I found that I need to use nw-gyp somehow. Firstly, I run this command in my project folder

> npm install ffi

Then I go to the folder ./node_modules/ffi and tried to run this command:

> nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.30.0 --arch=x64

And what I have in my console:

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using nw-gyp@3.6.3
gyp info using node@8.11.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn D:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\dchar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\dchar\\Desktop\\nwjsdll\\node_modules\\ffi\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\dchar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\dchar\\.nw-gyp\\0.30.0\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\dchar\\.nw-gyp\\0.30.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\dchar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file="C:\\Users\\dchar\\.nw-gyp\\0.30.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib"',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnw_lib_file="C:\\Users\\dchar\\.nw-gyp\\0.30.0\\<(target_arch)\\nw.lib"',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\dchar\\Desktop\\nwjsdll\\node_modules\\ffi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dv13=1',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\dchar\\Desktop\\nwjsdll\\node_modules\\ffi\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  Building assembly file ..\..\..\deps\libffi\src\x86\win64.asm
   Assembling: ..\..\..\deps\libffi\src\x86\win64.asm
  prep_cif.c
  types.c
  raw_api.c
  java_raw_api.c
  closures.c
  ffi.c
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  ffi.vcxproj -> C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\ffi\build\Release\\libffi.lib
  ffi.cc
  callback_info.cc
  threaded_callback_invokation.cc
  win32-dlfcn.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\ffi.cc(111): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(114): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(123): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(124): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(125): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(126): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\ffi.cc(132): error C2039: 'ForceSet': is not a member of 'v8::Object' [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modul
es\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\.nw-gyp\0.30.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(3103): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
..\src\callback_info.cc(63): warning C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjs
dll\node_modules\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
..\src\ffi.cc(58): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'C:\U
  sers\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1618): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call'

..\src\ffi.cc(59): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
..\src\callback_info.cc(73): warning C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjs
dll\node_modules\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
  C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1618): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call'
..\src\ffi.cc(60): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
..\src\callback_info.cc(78): warning C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjs
dll\node_modules\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'C:\U
  sers\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1618): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call'

..\src\ffi.cc(63): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(64): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(65): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(78): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(88): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(91): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(94): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(97): warning C4996: 'Nan::ForceSet': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\dchar\desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan_maybe_43_inl.h(130): note: see declaration of 'Nan::ForceSet'
..\src\ffi.cc(367): warning C4996: 'Nan::Callback::Call': was declared deprecated [C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_
modules\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1618): note: see declaration of 'Nan::Callback::Call'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\dchar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nw-gyp\lib\build.js:261:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dchar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\nw-gyp\\bin\\nw-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=0.30.0" "--arch=x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\dchar\Desktop\nwjsdll\node_modules\ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.1
gyp ERR! nw-gyp -v v3.6.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Help me please!

Comment: Well... I just looked at `ffi` [package here](https://travis-ci.org/node-ffi/node-ffi/builds), and it shows, that the builds of that project are failing since december last year.

Comment: @LudovitMydla that’s not package what I use, I use npm install ffi

Answer (score 0):

nw-gyp doesn’t work with versions of node-WebKit 0.23.0+ So, that’s why you need to use version 0.22.3, because it’s the last version that you can use with nw-gyp.